# How do I fix sound distortion. Ubuntu 21.04 on Rasberry Pi 4

Tags: sound

I was previously on Ubuntu 20.10 and would often get a sound distortion(on YouTube etc.) when using Firefox. Closing then reopening the browser would cure the problem, at least until the next time. If I used Chromium then there was no problem, as was the case when I played videos or music from my own files.
However, I downloaded Ubuntu 21.04 yesterday and now I have this problem with any audio I try to play from any source.
I am very much a novice on Ubuntu, indeed I don't begin to be a techie in any way. So please please make any advice simple and clear for me.
Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following command from a terminal it will restore audio (and video which will also bug out when this happens).

systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service

Turning off PulseAudio timer scheduling is a possible permanent fix for this issue.

edit the file /etc/pulse/default.pa and change the line that says:

load-module module-udev-detect

to

load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0

After editing the file, reboot your computer for changes to take effect.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1899953

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem has actually become much more intermittent since a subsequent Ubuntu update so, being the novice I am, I might just leave well alone! But I will keep a note of your reply for future reference. Thanks again.